# PHP7.2 libsodium doesn't seem to load macros

Tags: php, centos, libsodium

Hello I'm trying to deploy a intranet web server at my house, so I installed centOS on a machine, together with apache, php7.2 and mysql. However, my php application depends on libsodium for data encryption, so I ran `sudo yum install php-pecl-libsodium` followed by `sudo pecl install libsodium` to install libsodium, after that I added `extension=libsodium.so` to the end of php.ini file and it seemed to have worked since my `phpinfo()` is as follows:

[image: print of phpinfo() that shows libsodium info]

However when I try to load my application, this error occurs:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES - assumed 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/stm_asc/controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php on line 38

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: random_bytes() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given in /var/www/html/stm_asc/controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php:38 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/stm_asc/controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php(38): random_bytes('SODIUM_CRYPTO_S...') #1 /var/www/html/stm_asc/controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php(56): asc\MySQL_DataMapper->__construct() #2 /var/www/html/stm_asc/views/login.php(11): asc\MySQL_DataMapper::getInstance() #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/stm_asc/controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php on line 38
```

Here is MySQL_DataMapper.php on line 38:

[image]

So it seems like the macro `SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES` is not loading, I know this code works because it works on the machine I developed the system in, and it is documented as such [here](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/04-secretkey-crypto.md). So it is some sort of configuration problem for this new system, maybe I am missing another library that I don't remember? Thank You.

Comment: You're probably running into this issue... https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php/issues/172

Comment: If you're on PHP 7.2  you shouldn't need to install anything from pecl - the extension is bundled with PHP itself.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but that did not help.

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956155/php-random-bytes-with-sodium-integer-error